# unable to create a ros package in pr2_controller tutorial

Tags: ros, package, rosmake, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorial, Using the low-level robot base controllers to drive the robot.
I got a pr2 in gazebo and rosran the pr2 controller manager. When I try to
roscreate-pkg drive_base_tutorial roscpp geometry_msgs this is what the terminal looks like:
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Created package directory /home/roger/catkin_ws/src/drive_base_tutorial
Created include directory /home/roger/catkin_ws/src/drive_base_tutorial/include/drive_base_tutorial
Created cpp source directory /home/roger/catkin_ws/src/drive_base_tutorial/src
Created package file /home/roger/catkin_ws/src/drive_base_tutorial/Makefile
Created package file /home/roger/catkin_ws/src/drive_base_tutorial/manifest.xml
Created package file /home/roger/catkin_ws/src/drive_base_tutorial/CMakeLists.txt
Created package file /home/roger/catkin_ws/src/drive_base_tutorial/mainpage.dox

Please edit drive_base_tutorial/manifest.xml and mainpage.dox to finish creating your package

I am using 12.04 ubuntu and groovy. export
declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=""
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="groovy"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros"

and cd is in catkin_ws/src.

Please help. I do not know how to proceed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150701/unable-to-create-a-ros-package-in-pr2_controller-tutorial/) by [Ros_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/14601/ros_newbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you're trying to follow a rosbuild tutorial and create a rosbuild package in a catkin workspace.

The PR2 packages are not catkinized in Groovy. You should instead set up a overlay rosbuild workspace for working with the PR2 controllers on Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ros_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/14601/ros_newbie/) on 2014-04-09**:
Thanks. It helped.